# Session is unstable and seems to refer to two things?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a method in my application controller that sets an object to a session variable holding an object (I know it's not good, but I didn't write it. And the object is not stored in the database):

```
def current_wine_club_order
  if session[:dynamic_wine_club_order] && session[:dynamic_wine_club_order] != ''
    return session[:dynamic_wine_club_order]
  else
    return WineClubOrderService.new()
  end
end
```

This code in my controller breaks at `logger.debug { "#{@wine_club_order.inspect}" }`:

```
def new
  @wine_club_order = current_wine_club_order
  logger.debug { "#{@wine_club_order.inspect}" }
  @wine_club_order.current_user = current_user
  @wine_club_order.clear_errors!

  self.current_wine_club_order = @wine_club_order
  logger.debug { "#{@wine_club_order.inspect}" }
end
```

So when I debug, this is what I get in my shell:

```
    >> session
    !! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>
    >> session[:dynamic_wine_club_order]
    !! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>
    >> session[:what]
    => nil
    >> session.class
    => Rack::Session::Abstract::SessionHash
    >> session
    !! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>
    >> session.nil?
    => false
```

I don't get what's going on. Is session nil? Why is it giving me mixed answers? And in one of my before filters in my application controller, I print what the session[:dynamic_wine_club_order] value is, and it exists on every request:

My log:

`session[:dynamic_wine_club_order] = #<WineClubOrderService:0x007f8a9a606ef0>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was because the object I was storing in the session had similar non-ActiveRecord object instances as its instance variables. What I did was create another session variable just for containing the associated object and setting it explicitly to the original object's instance variable's value.